# Need some help breaking down a statement: the polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[X_1, X_2, ... , X_n]$ is the free commutative ring on n generators

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is a statement from Algebraic Geometry that I'm having some trouble parsing:

$\Bbb Z[X_1, X_2, ... , X_n]$ is the free commutative ring on $n$-generators.

I understand Z is a polynomial ring, meaning, when you add two polynomials and multiply two polynomials you still get a polynomial. Also, I understand commutative, but what does "free" mean? and what does it mean for it to have $n$-generators?

Comment: I believe the $Z$ in the statement is $\mathbb{Z}$, the integers. So do not confuse the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ with the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, "$Z$ is a polynomial ring" should be "$\mathbb{Z}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ is a polynomial ring". Also your "meaning" is not accurate. That is not what "is a polynomial ring" means; that just means it is closed under multiplication and addition.

Comment: Do you know what a free group is?

Comment: Do you know any category theory? e.g., at [this level?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/267410/742).

Comment: See [free commutative ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545767/free-commutative-ring-functor) at this site, too: *The free commutative ring on a set $X$ is the polynomial ring with variables the elements of $X$. This polynomial ring is the free (additive) abelian group on the free (multiplicative) abelian monoid on $X$*

Comment: What is your definition for this ring ?

Answer (score 1):

"Free," in this case, means that For any set $X$ (free on $X$), there exists an injection map $f: X\to F$ such that for any function $g: X\to A$, where $A$ is any other $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, there is a unique $h: F\to A$ such that $ f\circ h=g$.

In our case $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. The injection is just given by $f(x_i)=x_i$, now suppose that $g:\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\to A$ is a function, let $a_i=g(x_i)$ the images of the $x_i$'s under $g$, we can define $h$ by setting $h(x_i)=a_i$, by linearity $h$ is extended to all $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and it is easy to show that $f\circ h=g$.

In general, it is the idea, but in any case, the type of morphisms changes depending on the category we are talking about.